# Highcharts - how to set color for part of chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, column-chart

I have a column chart that uses a gradient color and looks like this :

[image]

however I'd like to make certain parts grey, like that:

[image]

What would be the best course of action in this case? Should I split the data in different series or .. ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update point's color on load event.

```
point.update({
  color: '#4d4d4d'
});
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.update

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/j7j1j28v/